# How to use Objective-C dynamic library from C#?

Tags: c#, objective-c

How can I call a dynamic library written in Objective-C from C#?
Let's assume the library has a simple class like this:

```
@interface VideoRecorder : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithStringDestination:(nonnull NSString *)destination;

- (void)start;
- (void)stop;
- (void)pause;
- (void)resume;
@end
```

Should I wrap it somehow in a C# class? Probably I should use OBJC runtime methods like `objc_getClass` but unsure how to use that in C#.

Comment: Have you seen https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/

Comment: @Ralf the project I was asked to provide a OBJC library is not using Xamarin, pure C# app.